# UIAlertController for large amount of text with scrolling functionality?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, ios8

UIAlertController show small strings. when the size of string become larger. then some text from this alert is missing. is there any scrolling functionality available so that to scroll to the remaining text?

```
var alert = UIAlertController(title: "title here", message: "about 30 line text here", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil))
    self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

how to make an alert that show me text larger then 30 lines.  i use swift.

Comment: Don't do this. An alert is an inappropriate way to communicate this amount of information.

Comment: what in alternate thing can be use for this? @mattt

Comment: Odd.  I think I remember it working for long text with a vertical swipe a few months ago.   But now I find it is not working in my Objective-C code either.  My initial suspicion is that some of my underlying settings that relate to my own scrolling controls are interfering.  But, I haven't checked it out yet.

Answer (score 5):

It works without effort in the Playgrounds:

```
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport

PlaygroundPage.current.needsIndefiniteExecution = true
let window = UIWindow()
let viewController = UIViewController()
window.rootViewController = viewController
window.makeKeyAndVisible()

let message = (1...1000).reduce("") { $0 + "\($1)\n" }

let alert = UIAlertController(title: "title here", message: message, preferredStyle: .alert)
alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "action here", style: .default, handler: nil))
viewController.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = window
```

I got 1000 scrollable lines:

[image: 1000 scrollable lines]

Comment: How do you import PlaygroundSupport. I don't have that module? Thanks

Comment: @RJB if you're in an iOS project, then you don't need the lines of code relative to Playground. A Playground project is just to let you test things out without having to create an application. [PlaygroundSupport](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/playgroundsupport) is available at least on Xcode 8 and 9 and 10.

Comment: @Fattie do you have a FeedbackAssistant id?

Answer (score -2):

It works fine for me in Objective C:

```
 NSString* messageString = @"Enter your Long text here";

 UIAlertController *alertController = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Title"
                                                                     message:messageString
                                                              preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

 alertController.view.frame = [[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame];

 [alertController addAction:[UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@“OK”
                                                style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                                              handler:^(UIAlertAction *action){
                                                  [self okButtonTapped];
                                              }]];
 [self presentViewController:alertController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

For Swift you can use this Code:

```
let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Your Title", message: "Your Text", preferredStyle: .Alert)

let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .Cancel) { (action) in
    println(action)
}
alertController.addAction(cancelAction)

let destroyAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Destroy", style: .Destructive) { (action) in
    println(action)
}
alertController.addAction(destroyAction)

self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true) {
 // ...
}
```

Comment: this is objectice-c and also this is not working with long text. scrolling effect dosn't show when text is more then the screen size.

Comment: the swift version given in this answer is same like the question one. dosn't work for large text.